# What do I need to do so that each user lists his own follower?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

Hi, I'm making an app and I need to list each user's own followers. In Firebase, there is a collection, user ID and followers id in the field. I found the solution in the code below, but it lists all the users. I just want to list the user's followers.

My codes are as follows. What changes do I need to make?

followers_card

```
class FollowersCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final snap;

  const FollowersCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.snap,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FollowersCard> createState() => _FollowersCardState();
}

class _FollowersCardState extends State<FollowersCard> {
  
  List<String> followersList = <String>[];

  getdata() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      setState(() {
        // first add the data to the Offset object
        List.from(value.data()!['followers']);
      });
    });

    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      getdata();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        color: mobileBackgroundColor,
        child: Card(
          child: Column(children: [
            //Header
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                vertical: 4,
                horizontal: 16,
              ).copyWith(right: 0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 16,
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                      widget.snap['photoUrl'],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            widget.snap['username'],
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ]),
        ));
  }
}
```

followers_screen

```
class FollowersScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FollowersScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FollowersScreen> createState() => _FollowersScreenState();
}

class _FollowersScreenState extends State<FollowersScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Image.asset(
          'Resim/logo.png',
          height: 50,
        ),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
        builder: (context,
            AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => FollowersCard(
              snap: snapshot.data!.docs[index].data(),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `getData` method (in follower_card) is setting up the state but you are not assigning that to any of the local variables. I'd update your setState with `setState(){followesList = List.from(value.data()!['followers'])}`. That way you will have the followersID stored in the local variable and can use the listViewBuilder to  build the list of followers.

Comment: I made the changes you said, but nothing has changed

Comment: Can you please update the code with your new ListViewBuilder so I can see?

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution but there might be some typos as I do not know your whole codebase. Take a look at the code below. Please let me know if that doesn't work so I can update this code :D

```dart
class FollowersCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final snap;

  const FollowersCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.snap,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FollowersCard> createState() => _FollowersCardState();
}

class _FollowersCardState extends State<FollowersCard> {
  
  List<dynamic> followersList = []; // shouldn't use dynamic

  getdata() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .get()
        .then((value) async {
            // get followerIds
            List<String> follwerIds = List.from(value.data()!['followers']);
            // loop through all ids and get associated user object by userID/followerID
            for (int i = 0; i < follwerIds.length; i++) {
               var followerId = follwerIds[i];
               var data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection("users")
                    .doc(followerId)
                    .get();
                
                // push that data into followersList variable as we are going 
                // to use that in listViewBuilder 
                followersList.add(data);
            }
        setState(() {});
    });

    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      getdata();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     // use the listView builder to render the list of followers card
    return SingleChildScrollView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: followersList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    var followerItem = followersList[index];

                    return _buildFollowersCard(followerItem['photoUrl'], followerItem['username']);
                }
            ),
    )
  }

  Widget _buildFollowersCard(String photoUrl, String username) {
    return Container(
        height: 70,
        width: double.infinity,
        color: mobileBackgroundColor,
        child: Card(
          child: Column(children: [
            //Header
            Container(
              height: 40,
              width: double.infinity,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                vertical: 4,
                horizontal: 16,
              ).copyWith(right: 0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 16,
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                     photoUrl,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            username,
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ]),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: followerId and followerData Undefined name 'followerData'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name. Gives a fault

Comment: Apologies! Please udpate `itemCount: followerData.length,` line with `itemCount: followersList.length,`. Missed that one!

Comment: Undefined name 'followerId'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.